# CSS file not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

guys i have a css file "menu.css" i called it in the head of my master page but it does not seem to work.

```
  <link href="CSS/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

i tried many alternatives such as

```
 <link id="Link1" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/CSS/menu.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css"/>
```

But all to no avail. However when i paste the content of the css in the master page head there by eliminating the css file, it then works. I really don't understand what the error is. All seem ok but it is not doing as expecteed. Below is my Master page. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Debt.master.cs" Inherits="Debt.Debt" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
  <link id="Link2" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/CSS/menu.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Members Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">



    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 


    <style type="text/css">

        * { margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body { background:#555 url(images/back.jpg); }
#menu { top:30px; }
#copyright {
    margin:100px auto;
    width:80%;
    font:12px 'Trebuchet MS';
    color:#bbb;
    text-indent:20px;
    padding:40px 0 0 0;
}
#copyright a { color:#bbb; }
#copyright a:hover { color:#fff; }



        .style1
        {

        }

            .ModalBackground  
            {  
                  background-color:Gray;  
                  filter: alpha(opacity=60);  
                  opacity: 0.6;  
                  z-index: 10000;  
            }  

            .ModalPopup  
            {  
                  background-color:White;  
                  border-width:3px;  
                  border-style:solid;  
                  border-color:Gray;  
                  padding:5px;  
                  width: 350px;  
                  height:210px; 
            }  
    </style>
     <link id="Link1" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/CSS/menu.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="CSS/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/menu.js"></script>
</head>

<body runat="server">
```

Comment: What is the structure of your files?

Comment: Is there any error in your console? Please check your path specified

Comment: Nope there is none. Moreover, when i paste the style in the header instead of calling the file, it works. I am confused why calling css file isn't working?

Comment: inspect the css link in chrome and see what is the error in path

Comment: Check whether you css file in included in project.If not then include it.

Comment: Are you using aspnet_membership?

Comment: try this **href="/CSS/menu.css"** instead of this **href="CSS/menu.css"**

Comment: Sorry , i realized the css works, what is not working are the images called from the css. I have the images in the folder images and are called like this "background:url(images/menu.png) repeat-x 0 center;"

Comment: again, try **"/images/menu.png"** instead of **images/menu.png**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys for all the help. I figured what the error was. It was the images path form the CSS. i called the images as follows

```
 background:url(images/columns.png) no-repeat;
background:url(images/subitem.png) no-repeat;
```

For some reason, it does not recognizes the above images path. However when i changed to

```
background:url(/images/columns.png) no-repeat;
background:url(/images/subitem.png) no-repeat;
```

That is adding a slash before the folder name. It works fine now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012 you can simply drag any CSS or JS file from the solution browser into your HTML document, and the editor creates the link statement for you. I personally prefer this approach as it eliminates the chance of path errors.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks. Thats how i do mine as well. i did many and all are working except this one.

Comment: Have you tried to use a developer tool in Chrome/Firefox/IE to see if the CSS file is actually loaded? Also, remember that browsers usually cache CSS/JS files, so Ctrl+R or F5 could load recent changes.

Comment: when i inspect on chrome, i can view my css and therefore i prusumed its loaded. But it still does not seem to work.

Comment: Okey, now I am just guessing: Could it be that the runat=server in the head tag has something to do with it? After all, the css should be run on the client, not the server.